# Testing file formats in a shell script

Tags: shell, file-format

What I want is for this script to test if a file passed to it as a parameter is an ASCII file or a zip file, if it's an ascii echo "ascii", if it's a zip echo "zip", otherwise echo "ERROR".

Here's what I have at the moment

```
filetype = file $1
isAscii=`file $1 | grep -i "ascii"`
isZip=`file $1 | grep -i "zip"`

if [ $isAscii -gt "0" ] then echo "ascii";
else if [ $isZip -gt "0" ] then echo "zip";
else echo "ERROR";
fi
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this just checks to see if the file *contains* `ascii` or `zip` - which is no guarantee of the file type!

Comment: @Wayne what do you mean? `man file` says it determines the file type.

Comment: @WayneWerner: no, he's using the file(1) program which does look inside the files.

Comment: Yusuf, I think the first line is wrong, try deleting it to begin with. And then, what's the specific problem with the script?

Comment: here's the output after running `sh myscript.sh myfile`    myscript.sh: 1: filetype: not found
myscript.sh: 6: Syntax error: "else" unexpected (expecting "then")

Comment: As this is bash, you should be writing `elif`, not `else if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `file` command, try `-b --mime-type`. Here is an example of filtering on MIME types:

```
#!/bin/sh
type file || exit 1
for f; do
    case $(file -b --mime-type "$f") in
        text/plain)
            printf "$f is ascii\n"
            ;;
        application/zip)
            printf "$f is zip\n"
            ;;
        *)
            printf "ERROR\n"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are running the file/grep commands and checking their return codes is not right.  You need to do something like this:

```
if file "$1" | grep -i ascii; then
    echo ascii
fi
```

Before, you were capturing the textual output of the file/grep pipeline into the variable and then comparing it with the number 0 as a string.  The above will use the actual return value of the command, which  is what you need.

Comment: So that the output of grep does not intermingle with the intended output, you should send it to /dev/null: `if file "$1" | grep -i ascii > /dev/null; then`

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko: sure, or even better, use grep --quiet.